# Group iMessage mixed up ID

Tags: messages

I responded to a group iMessage, but it showed up as being a response from my wife.  She also has an iPhone, but our phone numbers, email addresses and Apple IDs are all different.  How in the world did this happen?  And how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

In your settings under **Messages**, check your settings under **Send & Receive**. It will show you what you are receiving Messages via (phone number and email(s)). Do any of your wife's contact details show up?

Comment: No.  Just my contact information.  That's why it is so strange.  The other person in the group message saw my message as from my email address which is NOT how it usually appears for him, but at least it was from me!  :-)

Comment: So it sent from your email address which is probably what the person that added you to the group used to add you, then your friend that thought it was from your wife has that email in his contacts as your wife's email address